# Strange gap above the taskbar in desktop after connecting another screen

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, taskbar

I connected another screen today, just a simple DVI connector.
I set the settings to **extend** the screen from the main screen.

After connecting the screen, it is working as expected.

But, there is that gap between the bottom most icons to the taskbar:
http://prntscr.com/5elpqg

The icons is set to arrange automatically.

Where is this gap came from and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**: I didn't touch any setting that might effect that, the icons were arranged without the gap, but as soon as i finished connecting it has appeared.

**EDIT2**: I don't know if it any help but the second screen I connected is 23" and the main screen is 24".

Comment: If you unhook the newly added screen, do they go back to how they were before you plugged it in?  Are both screens set to their optimal resolutions?  Does the original monitor's resolution change after you hook up the second?

Comment: When the newly added screen is not connected, yes, it does appear to solve the problem. both screen is set to their optimal resolutions. And not it does not change after connecting the second screen.

Comment: Are both monitors set to the same resolution?

Comment: Yes they both set to the same resolution